# Jquery JSON not displaying data

Tags: jquery, css, json, ajax, html

I have been searching for hours and can't seem to find where the issue is in my code. I have tried several resources and searched different sites. When the "Get JSON Data" is clicked nothing appaears below. Can someone look at the code and see where I'm going wrong please.

Many thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#clickme').click(function(e) {

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

      var items = [];

      $.each(data, function(key, val) {

        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');

      });

      $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'interest-list',
        html: items.join('')
      }).appendTo('#ajaxjson');



    });

    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/hide_img.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/fadein_out.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/increaseTextSize.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/hideVideo.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/showVideo.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/ChangeHeader.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/eventHover.js"></script>
  <script src="ajaxload.js"></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script src="scripts/form_tooltip.js"></script>

  <style>
    .mma {
      font-size: 75%;
      color: ;
    }
    .important {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 50px;
    }
    .blue {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>

  <title>Mixed Martial Arts</title>

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 id="headertext">Mixed Martial Arts<span class="color"></span></h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li id="hideshowimg"><a href="#">Hide/Show Image</a>
          </li>
          <li id="increaseText"><a href="#">Increase Text</a>
          </li>
          <li id="showVideo"><a href="#">ShowVideo</a>
          </li>
          <li id="changecolor"><a href="#">Colour</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="hero-image">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="" class="button-1">Fade Out/In</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="features">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li class="feature-1">
          <h4 class="feature1-heading">What is MMA</h4>
          <p class="mma">MMA is a full-contact combat sport that allows for different techniques to grapple and strike their oppentent.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="feature-2">
          <h4>Common Disciplines</h4>
          <a href="#" id="clickme">Get JSON Data</a>
          <p id="ajaxjson"></p>


          <li class="feature-3">
            <h4>Competitions</h4>
            <p class="mma">There are many competitions that fighters can fight in such as Ultimate Fighting Championship (UFCPride, CageWars, Clan Wars and many more. MMA is the fastest growing sport today!</p>
          </li>
          <div class="clear"></div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="primary-content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <article>
        <h3>What is MMA?</h3>
        <a href="" class="button-video">Hide Video</a>

        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PnUmcL07xnY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div id="cta">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h3>Contact Form!</h3>
      <p>
        <form>
          First name:
          <br>
          <input id="txtName" title="Please input your firstname!" type="text" name="firstname">
          <br>Last name:
          <br>
          <input id="txtSurname" title="Please input your lastname!" type="text" name="lastname">
        </form>
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="button-2">Submit</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="footer-info">
        <p>Copyright 2015 Diarmuid Bogner.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

```
{

    "one": "Judo",
    "two": "Karate",
    "three": "Boxing",

}
```

Comment: Could you please post only the applicable HTML and better describe the exact nature of your problem? Are you getting an error in your JavaScript console? What is happening to the HTTP AJAX request? Are you getting back an error status code?

Comment: Is your `click` handler running? Does your `getJSON` callback run? Are there any errors in your [JS console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Answer (score 0):

See what following, sure that the ajax request returns what you expect!

```js
function DataCtrl($) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.btn = $('#btn');

  self.loadData = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    $  
//      .getJSON('data.json') // we need to comment, ajax isn't available
      .when({"one": "Judo", "two": "Karate", "three": "Boxing" }) // this is just a mock for the working example
      .then(function(data) {
        var listItems = [];
        
        for(var i in data) {
          if(!data.hasOwnProperty(i)) { continue; }
          
          listItems.push('<li id="listItem-'+ i +'">'+ data[i] +'</li>');
        }
      
        return listItems;
      })
      .then(function(items) {
        
        return $('<ul />', {
          html: items
        });
      })
      .then(function(list) {
        return $('#result').append(list);
      })
    ;
    
    
  };
  
  self.btn.click(self.loadData.bind(self));
}


jQuery(document).ready(DataCtrl);
```

```css
#result { width: 100%; min-height: 10em; background: lightseagreen; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Load Data</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Hi this display what I need it to display however I need it extract and display this information from the JSON file. Also does it have to be out putted to a div as the div is not display correctly.

Comment: in my snippet I've commented the line with *.getJSON('data.json')* because in stackoverflow it's impossible to perform xhr requests, so, you have to **uncomment** that line, and, the following line: **.when({"one": "Judo", "two": "Karate", "three": "Boxing" })** is written for this example only, you must remove that line using the uncommented previous...